# Solution for, "onpopstate" event which is not working in chrome, but working fine in IE and FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

When a user press the browser back button I want to alert the user, for that to capture the browser back button event I am using onpopstate event as show below. But the problem is the event is working fine in IE and FireFox but it is not being triggered in chrome. Kindly help me with this, Thanks.

```
$(window).on('popstate', function () {
    this.alert("Do you really want to leave the page?");
});
```

Using Chrome 75

Comment: Have you looked into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14748452/binding-popstate-event-not-working

Comment: Yeah!! I had checked with the same before, its working fine with chrome version below 34, unfortunately I'm using chrome 75. Thank You.

Comment: Working perfectly on `Version 75.0.3770.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)` You should check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/29500804/6517383 as well

Answer (score 0):

The pop state event is only triggered if you have added one or more items to the history state. You can get around it without actually pushing by replacing the state on page load, with a default value, that should trigger your event.

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.addEventListener('pageshow', fncName);
```

This worked for me when I tried to check if the browser back button is pressed, it was triggered.